# JQuery grep(...) VS native JavaScript filter(...) function performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, native, execution-time

I measured the execution times of those two functions:

- jQuery [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function
- Native JavaScript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

The execution of following methods have been measured using Chrome Profiles tool:

```
// jQuery GREP function
function alternative1(words, wordToTest) {
  return $.grep(words, function(word) {
    return wordToTest.indexOf(word) != -1;                    
  });
}

// Native javascript FILTER function        
function alternative2(words, wordToTest) {
  return words.filter(function(word) {
    return wordToTest.indexOf(word) != -1;                    
  });
}
```

Array of `words` was constructed of 1 million randomly generated strings. Each method was run 20 times. On my surprise `jQuery` grep function was faster.

Execution times (20 executions):

- jQuery [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function **26,31s**
- Native JavaScript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function **34,66s**

You can repeate measurings on this [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfhRC/17/) - it will take some time to execute so be patient.

Is there any explanation why jQuery [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function is faster then **native** JavaScript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function?

PS: This questions was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012721/617996).

Comment: Looking for the explanation? Try taking a look at [**the implementation of grep**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L712). As for testing performance, use [**JSPerf**](http://jsperf.com/) instead of making a script that can freeze the browser.

Comment: I put it into [**a test suite in jsPerf**](http://jsperf.com/filterings). I reduced it to `100 000` elements though, even `1 000` is fine

Comment: @Alexander thanks for porting JSFiddle code to JSPerf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By comparing the actual jQuery function `$.grep` uses on the page

```
function (a, b, c) {
    var d = [],
        e;
    c = !! c;
    for (var f = 0, g = a.length; f < g; f++) e = !! b(a[f], f), c !== e && d.push(a[f]);
    return d
}
```

(check [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.grep) for non-minified, thanks [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417685/alexander)) against [the algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.20) specified for

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

It looks to me like `.filter` forces its `this` to *Object*, checks the callback `IsCallable` and sets `this` in it as well as checking for existence of property in each iteration, whereas `.grep` assumes and skips these steps, meaning there is slightly less going on.

Combine this with how good the JavaScript compiler in Chrome is and you might find the speed difference.

Adding some of these into `$.grep` would make it look like

```
function (elems, callback, inv, thisArg) {
    var ret = [],
        retVal;
    inv = !!inv;
    for (var i = 0, length = elems.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (i in elems) { // check existance
            retVal = !!callback.call(thisArg, elems[i], i); // set callback this
            if (inv !== retVal) {
                ret.push(elems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and take about the same time as `.filter` [(modified Alexander's jsperf)](http://jsperf.com/filterings/2).

Comment: You may want to look at [a non-minified version of `$.grep`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.grep) though

Comment: @Alexander thanks, I've linked that in and credited you (twice because I made use of your jsperf too)