# jQuery's $.grep() vs. Underscore's _.filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Given an array, both `$.grep` and `_.filter` return an array of elements for which a predicate function returns true. Is there any known performance difference between the two?

It looks like `$.grep` is faster than the native `filter` as seen here:
[JQuery grep(...) VS native JavaScript filter(...) function performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091065/jquery-grep-vs-native-javascript-filter-function-performance)

*However, this doesn't mention the Underscore.js method.*

Comment: I'll go with Native Javascripts' [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Is this a true duplicate? Is `_.filter` the same as native `filter()`? Though thank you, @Tushar, if that is most performant.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this continues to be marked duplicate— can someone please explain how this duplicate question answers mine? I'm asking about an Underscore.js function...